# prometheus.NewHistogram() api for histogram metric type

Tags: go, prometheus

Using `github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus` library to instrument GO app, for metrics:

In the below code:

```
requestDurations := prometheus.NewHistogram(prometheus.HistogramOpts{
     Name: "http_request_duration_seconds"
     Help: "A Histogram of the http request duration in secconds"

     // Cumulative bucket upper bounds
     Buckets: []float64{0.05, 0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 2,5, 5, 10}
})

requestDurations.Observe(0.42)
```

---

1. What does `Buckets: []float64{0.05, 0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 2,5, 5, 10}` imply?
2. What does `requestDurations.Observe(0.42)` imply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the package documentation states:

> Buckets defines the buckets into which observations are counted. Each
> element in the slice is the upper inclusive bound of a bucket. The
> values must be sorted in strictly increasing order. There is no need
> to add a highest bucket with +Inf bound, it will be added
> implicitly. The default value is DefBuckets.

Histogram counts observations in buckets. With this declaration, you declare buckets with upper limits of 0.05, 0.1, 0.25, ..., 5, 10,  +inf. Each observation will be counted in one of these buckets. For instance, the `Observe(0.42)` will increment the buckets whose upper limits are >=0.5.

Comment: Actually it is increments all the buckets starting with bucket that has upper limit 0.5. Looks like this is cumulative

Comment: Yes, edited the answer to reflect that